# how to return more then 1 variable data from php user define function

Tags: php, return-value

I am calling mail_data function and passing userid

```
function mail_data($userid)
{
................
................
$query="select * from table where userid='$userid'";
$rs=mysql_query($query,$con);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)
$fname=$row['fname'];
$lname=$row['lname'];
$mail=$row['mail'];
//i want to return 3 variables from here
}
```

Is there any method to return more then  variable from any function ?

Comment: Can't you return an associative array?

Comment: Just make an array of all the variables you want to send and send that array.

Comment: Or you know, just return `$row`

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
return $row;
```

OR

```
$data['fname'] = $row['fname'];
$data['lname'] = $row['lname'];
$data['mail'] = $row['mail'];

return $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Return statement returns value for only single variable at a time.

So for returning values for multiple variables at a time you need to define an array variable for holding multiple values and return that array variable from the function